# Validation plugin for a Boolean field

Tags: views, 8, plugins

I want to contextually filter my View with a boolean field, for which the "On" value is "New," so using a URL like /view/url/new.

I first tried basic validation, but that would only work if my URL were /view/url/1.

So I wrote my own validation plugin to validate "New" as if it were "1".

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module_validation\Plugin\views\argument_validator;

use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\argument_validator\ArgumentValidatorPluginBase;

/**
 * Validate the New boolean.
 *
 * @ingroup views_argument_validate_plugins
 *
 * @ViewsArgumentValidator(
 *   id = "my_module_validation",
 *   title = @Translation("MYMODULE Validation")
 * )
 */
class MyModuleValidation extends ArgumentValidatorPluginBase {

  public function validateArgument($argument) {
    if($argument == 'new' || $argument == 'New' || $argument == '1') {
      return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

So I'm able to apply this fine (and I can tell it's being used with a drupal_set_message() thrown inside that block), but it still doesn't work. Results only appear if I add the /view/url/1 and not the /view/url/new like I want.

Please help me understand what I've done wrong and how I can fix it.

Comment: Have you checked that `$argument` is what you expect it to be at that point?

Comment: Yes, it's whatever is in the URL, whether that's "new", "all", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add $this->argument->argument = '1'; to the above code, it works:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module_validation\Plugin\views\argument_validator;

use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\argument_validator\ArgumentValidatorPluginBase;

/**
 * Validate the New boolean.
 *
 * @ingroup views_argument_validate_plugins
 *
 * @ViewsArgumentValidator(
 *   id = "my_module_validation",
 *   title = @Translation("MYMODULE Validation")
 * )
 */
class MyModuleValidation extends ArgumentValidatorPluginBase {

  public function validateArgument($argument) {
    if($argument == 'new' || $argument == 'New' || $argument == '1') {
      $this->argument->argument = '1';
      return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```